# Django datetime localization

Tags: django, localization, django-1.4

I want to output a `datetime` object (with timezone info set to UTC) in a Django template.  I have I18N, L10N, and TZ support all on in the settings.  I've also added the `LocaleMiddleware` and set the language settings.  Settings also contains my local timezone as the default.  If I simply do `{{ mydatetime }}` in the template than it properly gives the information in the local timezone.  However `{{ mydatetime|localize }}` seems to always output the datetime in UTC.

Now, I know you're supposed to call `django.utils.timezone.activate()` to report the current user's timezone (which I'm not doing), but the docs seem to indicate that if you don't use that to report the user's timezone that it uses the default.

Also, does the `localize` filter get used on datetimes automatically?  Is the only purpose of having an explicit call is for when you use `{% localize off %}` and you want a one-off localization made?